# Plotting Luv colors; replicating figure 6.11 from the ggplot2 book

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, color-space

I am trying to replicate figure 6.11 from Hadley Wickham's [ggplot2 book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387981403), which plots R colors in Luv space; the colors of points represent themselves, and no legend is necessary.
[image]

Here are two attempts:

```
library(colorspace)
myColors <- data.frame("L"=runif(10000, 0,100),"a"=runif(10000, -100, 100),"b"=runif(10000, -100, 100))
myColors <- within(myColors, Luv <- hex(LUV(L, a, b)))
myColors <- na.omit(myColors)
g <- ggplot(myColors, aes(a, b, color=Luv), size=2)
g + geom_point() + ggtitle ("mycolors")
```

[image]

Second attempt:

```
other <- data.frame("L"=runif(10000),"a"=runif(10000),"b"=runif(10000))
other <- within(other, Luv <- hex(LUV(L, a, b)))
other <- na.omit(other)
g <- ggplot(other, aes(a, b, color=Luv), size=2)
g + geom_point() + ggtitle("other")
```

[image]

There are a couple of obvious problems:

1. These graphs don't look anything like the figure. Any suggestions on
   the code needed?
2. The first attempt generates a lot of NA fields in the Luv
   column (only ~3100 named colors out of 10,000 runs, versus ~9950 in
   the second run). If L is supposed to be between 0-100 and u and v
   between -100 and 100, why do I have so many NAs in the first run? I have tried rounding, it doesn't help.
3. Why do I have a legend?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting strange colors because `aes(color = Luv)` says "assign a color to each unique string in column `Luv`".  If you assign `color` outside of `aes`, as below, it means "use these explicit colors".   I think something like this should be close to the figure you presented.

```
require(colorspace)
x <- sRGB(t(col2rgb(colors())))
storage.mode(x@coords) <- "numeric" # as(..., "LUV") doesn't like integers for some reason
y <- as(x, "LUV")
DF <- as.data.frame(y@coords)
DF$col <- colors()
ggplot(DF, aes( x = U, y = V)) + geom_point(colour = DF$col)
```

Comment: Or better, use `scale_colour_identity`

Comment: @hadley. I am not sure how to do that. 'ggplot(DF, aes( x = U, y = V, fill=colors())) + geom_point() + scale_color_identity()' does not work -- gives black dots and labels. Can you please show a small reproducible example? Thanks

Comment: `ggplot(DF, aes(x = U, y = V)) + geom_point(aes(colour = col)) +
     scale_colour_identity()` works for me under R-2.15.2 and ggplot2-0.9.3.